# HashMap with object value as key

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hash

Say I have 2 lists of Nodes (Node is some comparable object, the details don't matter). I'd like to find which Nodes appear on both lists - not necessarily the same Node object, but Nodes whose compareTo returns 0.

For example, nodeA is on list A and nodeB is on list B. They are NOT the same Node but nodeA.compareTo(nodeB) will return 0 (equality).

I'd like to solve this by iterating over list A and putting the nodes in a HashMap/HashSet, then iterating over list B and checking which nodes have already been inserted into the HashMap/HashSet. The issue is, this will not work as the Nodes will not be considered equal by the HashMap unless they are the same actual Node.

How can I solve this problem? Note that I am **not** looking for other solutions to this problem, but for an understanding of if (and how) I can use a HashMap, HashSet or another similar data structure in the given example scenario.

Comment: What hashcode returns?  What `nodeA.hashcode() == nodeB.hashcode()` returns?

Comment: In the case I'm interested in, it returns false.

Comment: This is the problem! HashMap/HashSet works with hashCode/equals!

Comment: If you want to use `compareTo` use a `TreeSet`. For HashMap you need `equals/hashCode` to be written correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this (if I am understanding this right) by overriding the equals and hashcode methods in the Node object to use the same criteria as the compareTo method.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You should use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) as it **relies on ordering, not on hashing**.</s>

**Update (WRONG! See update 3):** But you still have to make sure `a.compareTo(b)==0` iff `a.equals(b)` because the [implementation of `contains`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#1550) actually finds the corresponding element by the ordering, and then checks equality using `equals`!

**Update 2:** To use only the ordering, you could make the first list sorted (`Collections.sort(listA)`) and then check the result of `Collections.binarySearch(listA, nodeB)` for each `nodeB` from `listB`. When the result is `>=0` the `nodeB` was in `listA`, w.r.t their ordering. [The implementation of binarySearch uses only ordering](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#224), no equals involved. The complexity of this approach is `O(n log(n))` since each binary search is `O(log(n))` (`n` being size of the bigger of the lists -- sorting list A is also `O(n log(n))`), that is the same complexity as using TreeSet (`O(log n)` for both insert/contains).

**Update 3:** As pointed out in the comments, the `TreeSet` should do the work, as the `equals` is not used in the `TreeMap's` `containsKey`, but somewhere else. But the JavaDoc says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface.

And [docs for the `contains` method for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) (!) says:

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e
>   such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So it is still not a good idea  to use `TreeSet` with incosistent API. Who knows what *another* Java implementation may do in such a case. So I suggest sticking with the *Update 2* solution.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, but this would hurt runtime, correct? TreeSet basic actions are O(log(n)) rather than O(1).

Comment: @frrlod Yes, it would be slower than using HashMap, as you say. The HashMap complexity trick is based on having THE HASH (`O(1)` average, but `O(n)` worst case). When you have ordering, the best lookup you can have is `O(log(n))` (worst case) by binary search (used in TreeSet too), and when you have nothing like that, just _equality_ your lookup time is `O(n)` -- you have to look on every possible element.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make your own subclass of HashMap that overrides the containsValue(object value) function with one that fits your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TreeSet/TreeMap**. It uses **compareTo()** method instead of equals() and hashcode() which is what used while assigning Nodes in HashMap/HashSet.

Look at the following code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TestMaps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Node> set1 = new TreeSet<>();
    HashSet<Node> set2 = new HashSet<>();

    Node node1 = new Node(0, "First");
    Node node2 = new Node(0, "Second");

    System.out.println(set1.add(node1)); //Node1 added in TreeSet
    System.out.println(set2.add(node1));//Node1 added in HashSet
    System.out.println(set1.add(node2));//Node2 added in TreeSet
    System.out.println(set2.add(node2));//Node2 added in HashSet
}


}

class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
int i;
String name;

Node(int i, String n){
    this.i = i;
    this.name = n;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {

    return this.i - o.i;
}
}
```

Running this results into :

```
true
true
false
true
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: `TreeMap` uses `equals` on the object queried by `contains`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39406369/6749977).

Comment: are you sure on that because what I see in TreeSet Implementation. "contains" calls internally TreeMap "ContainsKey" method which in turn calls "getEntry" method which again uses "compareTo" or "compare". I did not see any reference for equals there.

Comment: @MartinMilichovsky That is wrong and I already pointed this out in the comments. Basically you ruined your good answer by adding that nonsense to your post.